# un problema: Parámetro de longitud no válido pasado a la función SUBSTRING. - Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Modifico el código con substring:  Hola amigos tengo un problema sale error y revisando todo el código es en este pedazo de código que lo acabo de cortar haber que ayuda me dan amigos.

```
select entrecalles,
    CASE charindex('/',entrecalles) WHEN 0 THEN (
        case charindex('_',entrecalles) when 0 then entrecalles else
        SUBSTRING(entrecalles, charindex('/', entrecalles)+1, len(entrecalles) - CHARINDEX('_', reverse(entrecalles)) - charindex('/', entrecalles)) 
    end
    )
    ELSE
        case charindex('_',entrecalles) when 0 then entrecalles else
    SUBSTRING(entrecalles, charindex('/', entrecalles)+1, len(entrecalles) - CHARINDEX('_', reverse(entrecalles)) - charindex('/', entrecalles))
    end
    end as Almacen from art (nolock)
```

Comment: En el código que recortaste no está contenida la función SUBSTRING por lo que no se puede evaluar el error. Coloca la consulta original. Salu2

Comment: a si es, esta reconociendo el left como un substring, ese el problema, prodria que modificar el código o no se como lo arias

Comment: Tendriamos que ver los datos, pero seguro una de esas funciones no encuentra el char que estas buscando, y entonces da una cantidad de caracteres invalidos

Comment: ahora modifique el codigo

Comment: este seria el código modificado y vuelve a salir el mismo error.

Comment: select entrecalles,
  CASE charindex('/',entrecalles) WHEN 0 THEN (
   case charindex('_',entrecalles) when 0 then entrecalles else
   SUBSTRING(entrecalles, charindex('/', entrecalles)+1, len(entrecalles) - CHARINDEX('_', reverse(entrecalles)) - charindex('/', entrecalles)) 
  end
  )
  ELSE
   case charindex('_',entrecalles) when 0 then entrecalles else
  SUBSTRING(entrecalles, charindex('/', entrecalles)+1, len(entrecalles) - CHARINDEX('_', reverse(entrecalles)) - charindex('/', entrecalles))
  end
  end as Almacen from art (nolock)

Comment: Como te indica gbianchi el problema está en los datos donde uno o mas de ellos no cumple con alguna de las condiciones de búsqueda, si son muchos datos deberás buscarlos y corregir la consulta para adaptarla, son muchos, como para apoyarse con https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

Comment: haciendo algunas pruebas un caso simple que dio como resultado el error en la misma función fue probar con el string "_ /", alguna condición de borde existe en los datos, debes revisar bien el corte de la cadena

Comment: la funcion que ejecuta esa cadena es extraer datos ejemplo 'datos/sofy_code'  separa 'datos'  'sofy'  'code'  , el codigo que muestra es para mostrar el la cadena del centro 'code'.